# Is there an isometric isomorphism between Sobolev space $H_{1}^{0}$ and $L^{2}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

We defined in class $H_{1}^{0}$ as the Hilbert space obtained as the closure in $W^{1}(G) = \{ u \in L^2(G) : \exists \partial_{j} u \in L^2(G), 1 \leq j \leq n \}$ of $\mathcal{D}(G) = \{ g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, C^{\infty}, supp(G) \subset \Omega ~compact\}$. My doubt is:

Is it true or false that Sobolev space $H_{1}^{0}$ and the Hilbert space $L^{2}(\Omega)$ are isometrically isomorphic?

Thanks!

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think they're isomorphic, but no isomorphism comes to my mind, so I'm having several doubts about it and I can't find a similar example on my book

Comment: What has led you to think that they are isomorphic? I don't know the answer myself, but adding a bit more detail and context to your question will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: You'll have to add some context (like the definition of $H^0_1$, how this question arose, why you think they are isometrically isometric or not), or your question is in danger to get closed.